# How to change a user's role?

Tags: user-roles

I have custom roles in my setup and I want to be able to automatically change a user's role thru a function. Say user A has a SUBSCRIBER role, how do I change it to EDITOR? When adding a role we just:

```
add_role( $role_name , $role_display_name , array( 'read' =>  true,
                                                   'edit_posts' => false,
                                                   'delete_posts' => false, ));
```

How about changing a role? Is there something like:

```
change_role($old_role, $new_role);
```

**UPDATE:**
I think this one will do:

```
$wp_user_object = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
$wp_user_object->set_role('editor');
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

See the [WP_User class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/), you can use this to add and remove roles for a user.

Specifically, a user's role can be modified by creating an instance of the `WP_User` class, and calling the `add_role`, `remove_role` or `set_role` methods depending on what your requirements are.

## Example

Removing the subscriber role, then adding the editor role.

```
// Making sure to adjust `3` to an appropriate user ID
$u = new WP_User( 3 );

// Remove role
$u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
$u->add_role( 'editor' );
```

The add and remove methods are probably most suited to use cases where users are given multiple roles.

If your aim is to simply switch a role, this is more easily done using the `set_role` method, like so.

```
// Making sure to adjust `10` to an appropriate user ID
$u = new WP_User( 10 );

// Switch role
$u->set_role( 'author' );
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: `remove_role()` and `add_rule()` save data to the database?

Comment: Yes @b_dubb, both methods save to db through the `update_user_meta()` method [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_user_meta/). See `add_role()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/add_role/) and `remove_role()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user/remove_role/)

Comment: That's pretty handy. Thanks.

Comment: `set_role()` will remove all roles and add the specified role in one command

Answer (score 33):

Just note that there is a simpler way to change the user role which is especially helpful when you do not know the current role of the user: `->set_role()`

Example:

```
// Fetch the WP_User object of our user.
$u = new WP_User( 3 );

// Replace the current role with 'editor' role
$u->set_role( 'editor' );
```

Comment: Remember that set_role will remove the previous roles of the user and assign the new role.

Comment: This is perfect for custom registration forms. First register users with no roles and after that add role when they confirm email.

Answer (score 4):

To extrapolate on t31os's answer you can slap something like this in your functions file if you want to do this programmatically based on a condition

```
$blogusers = get_users($blogID.'&role=student');

foreach ($blogusers as $user) {

    $thisYear = date('Y-7');
    $gradYear = date(get_the_author_meta( 'graduation_year', $user->ID ).'-7');

    if($gradYear < $thisYear) {
        $u = new WP_User( $user->ID );
        // Remove role
        $u->remove_role( 'student' );

        // Add role
        $u->add_role( 'adult' );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think your usage of `$blogID` is wrong. [`get_users()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_users) will use the current blog ID per default anyway.

Comment: yep, in my case the paste was just from a multisite example. I didn't define it here either so obviously it would throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$wuser_ID = get_current_user_id();
if ($wuser_ID)
    {
      // NOTE: Of course change 3 to the appropriate user ID
      $u = new WP_User( $wuser_ID );

      // Remove role
      $u->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

      // Add role
      $u->add_role( 'contributor' );
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the role of any user by editing the users profile. No need to add any more code when this option is already built into WordPress.

[image]

Or

You could use code to change all current users with the subscriber role to editor:

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

// Remove role
$current_user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

// Add role
$current_user->add_role( 'editor' );
```

Answer (score 1):

### There's a WordPress function for that!

I think it is best to use WordPress functions, if and when they are available.

You can use the [wp_insert_user()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_user) function, where one of the arguments that you will need to provide is the $userdata['role']. In this argument you can specify the role that you want to change the user into.

Comment: wp doesn't recognize that function. I got an "undefined function" error.

Comment: By the looks of it, wp_insert_user() seems to do the exact same.  When you provide an ID, that ID gets updated. No ID is adding new user. Don't really know what the difference between wp_update_user() and wp_insert_user() is, yet.

Answer (score 1):

you have to include the /wp-includes/registration.php, if you use the code as a stand alone script.
Regards
Uwe

Answer (score 1):

You can use [wp_update_user](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user). Your code shoud be like this:

```
<?php
    $user_id = 3;
    $new_role = 'editor';

    $result = wp_update_user(array('ID'=>$user_id, 'role'=>$new_role));

    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        // There was an error, probably that user doesn't exist.
    } else {
        // Success!
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a very old Post, but i have found that the roles for users are stored in `wp_usermeta` table with key `wp_capabilities` in `meta_key` column.

If you want to change the user role you can do it by this simple function.

```
function change_role($id, $new_role){
    GLOBAL $table_prefix;
    if(is_array($new_role)){
        $new_role_array = $new_role;
    }else{
        $new_role_array = array( $new_role => true );
    }
    return update_user_meta($id, $table_prefix.'capabilities', $new_role_array);
}
```

There is two way to use this function.

If you want to change the role for a single role.

```
change_role(2, 'editor'); // editor is the new role
```

Or if you want to add multi roles to the user, use the roles as array in the second parameter.

```
$roles_array = array('editor' => true, 'administrator' => true); // roles array
change_role(2, $roles_array);
```

Good luck.